Why do I get a "Invalid grant_type" error when I want to refresh the access token? - Netatmo API
I want to refresh the access token for the Netatmo API. I tried different things but I get every time the same error. I use MicroPython and the urequests lib for the requests.
The error is:
Status Code: 400
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

At first I tried, as it works for me in normal Python, to make a request post.
payload = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'client_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

response = requests.post("https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token", 
   data=payload)

The result was:
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
I found out that urequests can not handle it, because it does not know which protocol it has to use.
Next I converted it to a bytearry. Then I don't get the type error, but I get the error invalid_request
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

After that, I tried to set the headers, but I got the same error as without headers.
payload = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'client_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',}

payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
payload_bytes = bytearray(payload_json, 'utf-8')

response = requests.post('https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token', data=payload_bytes, headers=headers)

At the end I even tried to build the URL by hand, but I still get the invalid request error.
This is the URL I tried to build:
https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token?&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Can please somebody help me?

What is the back end or the api expecting?

@MadeInDreams The problem is: I don't really know. In the documentation is an example for a request, but I can not see there what the api expects. The link to the documentation is: https://dev.netatmo.com/apidocumentation/oauth#:~:text=Bearer%20%5BYOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN%5D-,Refreshing%20a%20token,-When%20you%20request
In normal Python it works as shown in the first code example I wrote.

As assumed is the problem, that the format is wrong and the urequests can not read the format. After a long conversation with ChatGPT is the solution to encode the URL.
The method ChatGPT gave me was:
def urlencode(params):
    encoded_str = ''
    for key, value in params.items():
        encoded_str += '{}={}&'.format(key, value)
    return encoded_str[:-1]

It works for me perfectly. So here is the complete code how it works for me:
import urequests as requests

def urlencode(params):
    encoded_str = ''
    for key, value in params.items():
        encoded_str += '{}={}&'.format(key, value)
    return encoded_str[:-1]

payload = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'client_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    }

payload_encoded = urlencode(payload)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.post('https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/token', data=payload_encoded, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)


My netatmo refresh token has also been expired (> 3 hrs old).
I have the same error here: I can not refresh the access - and refresh code. I used the 'ChatGPT' method/code as suggested by @Tabsy21. The output I get is:
400
{"error":"invalid_grant"}

